# how to search for a specific term within the xml and extract its value within the specific tag

Tags: bash, shell, tags, xmllint, extract-value

I am trying to figure out, first search the term within the specific tag (article tag) and then retrieve the value from that specific tag within the article tag.

I can retrieve the value from a specific tag,

```html
<article>
    <author>
        <name>Example Name 1</name>
        <title>example title 2</title>
    </author>
    <title>article title 1</title>
    <publicationDate>2022-02-12</publicationDate>
    <text>blah1 blah1 blah1</text>
    <reference>10000</reference>
</article>
<article>
    <author>
        <name>Example Name 2</name>
        <title>example title 2</title>
    </author>
    <title>article title 1</title>
    <publicationDate>2022-02-13</publicationDate>
    <text>blah1 blah1 blah1</text>
    <reference>10001</reference>
</article>
```

`xmllint    --xpath     "string(//title)"     file.xml`

But how can I search and then retrieve the value within the article tags? It will be each time a different reference number, then I need to extract the value from that specific reference.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your intention correctly, you should be able to parameterize your xpath search string using a bash variable containing the reference number that you are interested in.  Note, that I modified your example XML to be wrapped in  tags, so you will need to modify the xpath per your XML structure.

Script contents:

```
#!/bin/bash

ref_no=${1:-10001}
src_xml=${2:-/tmp/foo/s.xml}

title=$(xmllint --xpath "string(/articles/article[reference=${ref_no}]/title)" "${src_xml}")
printf "Reference: %s, Title: %s\n" "${ref_no}" "${title}"
```

Output:

```
$ ./script 10000
Reference: 10000, Title: article title 1

$ ./script 10001
Reference: 10001, Title: article title 2
```

For clarity, here is the test XML that I utilized:

```
<articles>
<article>
    <author>
        <name>Example Name 1</name>
        <title>example title 2</title>
    </author>
    <title>article title 1</title>
    <publicationDate>2022-02-12</publicationDate>
    <text>blah1 blah1 blah1</text>
    <reference>10000</reference>
</article>
<article>
    <author>
        <name>Example Name 2</name>
        <title>example title 2</title>
    </author>
    <title>article title 2</title>
    <publicationDate>2022-02-13</publicationDate>
    <text>blah1 blah1 blah1</text>
    <reference>10001</reference>
</article>
</articles>
```

Per the OP's question in the comments below, here is a variation if the  is a string:

Script contents:

```
#!/bin/bash

ref_no=${1:-a10001}
src_xml=${2:-/tmp/s.xml}

title=$(xmllint --xpath "//*[reference=\"${ref_no}\"]/title/text()" "${src_xml}")
printf "Reference: %s, Title: %s\n" "${ref_no}" "${title}"
```

Note that you have to escape the double quotes surrounding the `${ref_no}` variable and then use the `text()` function to extract the text from the  element.

Further, note that the source XML's second `<reference>` tag value was updated to 'a10001':

```
<reference>a10001</reference>
```

Output:

```
$ ./script a10001
Reference: a10001, Title: article title 2
```

Comment: thank you for your answer j_b.
Can you please explain me, 
what is the variable variation: 
ref_no=${1:-10001}
src_xml=${2:-/tmp/foo/s.xml}

is it first argument? I didn't see that kind of declaration. can you please enlight me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `ref_no` will take the value of the first parameter passed to the script or `10001` if no parameters are passed.   `src_xml` will take the value of the second parameter passed to the script or `/tmp/foo/s.xml` if no parameters are passed.  It is syntax for a default value for the variables.   You can change the values as needed or simply use only the parameters passed by changing to `ref_no=${1}` and `src_xml=${2}`

Comment: this topic can be closed, Thank you to everyone

Comment: additional question:  if there is a letter in the reference tag the search will not work. I already tried with the double quotes. It does not work, what might be the fix? ex: <reference>a10000</reference> it will not work. is it normal? Thank you for the great answer.

Comment: @learner, you have to change the xpath query to a textual search.   I will update my answer with this variation.

Comment: Dear j_b  thank you for your answer, it is working now even better. Before, some titles were not fully displayed in the output, Now all of them displayed completely,  Thank you for your help